# ASP.NET MVC2 Login form in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, master-pages, login-control

I'm trying to find an elegant way of having login form in the master page. That means unless user logs in, login form should appear on every page. (This is very common these days)

Taking the example that comes with MVC2 Application in Visual Studio I have created this:

```
public class MasterViewModel
{
    public string User { get; set; } // omitted validation attributes
    public string Pass{ get; set; }
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Every view model inherits from MasterViewModel

```
public class RegisterViewModel : MasterViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

My master page renders partial view

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<MyLogon.ViewModels.MasterViewModel>" %>
.....
            <div id="logindisplay">
                <% Html.RenderPartial("LogOn"); %>
            </div> 
......
```

Strongly-typed partial view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyLogon.ViewModels.MasterViewModel>" %>
    <%
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    %>
            Welcome <b><%= Html.Encode(Page.User.Identity.Name) %></b>!
            <div>[ <%= Html.ActionLink("Change Password", "ChangePassword", "Account") %> ]</div>        
            <div>[ <%= Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") %> ]</div>
    <%
        }
        else {
    %> 
        <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>

        <% using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account",FormMethod.Post)) { %>
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Account Information</legend>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.User) %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User) %>
                        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User) %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.Pass) %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <%= Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Pass) %>
                        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Pass) %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe) %>
                        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe) %>
                    </div>              
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        <% } %>
    <%
        }
    %>
```

Register page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyLogon.Models.RegisterViewModel>" %>
...
    <h2>Create a New Account</h2>
    <p>
        Use the form below to create a new account. 
    </p>
    <p>
        Passwords are required to be a minimum of <%= Html.Encode(ViewData["PasswordLength"]) %> characters in length.
    </p>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account" ,FormMethod.Post))
       { %>
        <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Account creation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Account Information</legend>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName) %>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName) %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName) %>
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email) %>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email) %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email) %>
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password) %>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%= Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password) %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password) %>
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword) %>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%= Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword) %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword) %>
                </div>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

Since all view models inherit from MasterViewModel LogOn partial view is always satisfied but I'm finding this solution very inelegant. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a partial view as you are but have different views based on the logged in status. Return one view for anonymous users with a login form/lunk to the register page and a second view for logged in users.

Partial views can have their own models which do not need to inherit from the master view model.

Inheriting models can cause problems later (It makes using `html.EditForModel()` or `.DisplayForModel()` tricky as they will render the common master view fields too).

Oh and in general, it's bad practice for the view to rely on anything outside the model - your test on `Request.IsAuthenticated` may be fine for now but if you want to be absolutely correct, you should have a `model.IsAuthenticated` property which is set by the action. That said, switching views will obviate this problem entirely.

**Edit:** One last improvement. On lines like this one:

```
Welcome <b><%= Html.Encode(Page.User.Identity.Name) %></b>!
```

Instead do:

```
Welcome <b><%: Page.User.Identity.Name %></b>!
```

Actually even better would be to only hit the model:

```
Welcome <b><%: model.Username %></b>!
```

(Note the `<%:` not `<%=`). This form of tag indicates that the contents should be HTML-encoded. What's even better is that if it encounters a `string`, it will encode it. If it encounters an `HTMLString`, it won't. All the .Net MVC functions return string or HTML string as appropriate so you can do this:

```
<%: html.EditFor(x => x.fieldname) %>
<%: model.somefield %>
```

The first will NOT be html encoded as `EditFor()` returns an `HTMLString`. The second WILL be encoded (if `somefield` is a standard string)

This will make your code both neater and more robust. You can also use this to dynamically generate HTML should you have to and have it encoded/not as appropriate. Eg we have some helper functions to handle including CSS/JS. They return HTMLStrings...

```
<%: Helper.IncludeCSS("SomeCSS.css") %>
```

Comment: "Use a partial view as you are but have different views based on the logged in status. Return one view for anonymous users with a login form/lunk to the register page and a second view for logged in users." Sorry I don't know If I got it right. What you descibed comes with MVC2 Application by default. The idea is to have Login on EVERY page until user logs in. So clicking on Register I will have two forms displayed. I'm using <%= not <%:  because I'm working with Visual Studio 2008

Comment: Ah, ok my only experience with MVC is MVC2 so my information may be suspect for MVC. Certainly in MVC2, I'd have a RenderPartial on the masterpage which points at an action. That action would return one of 2 views based on Request.IsAuthenticated. If Not Authenticated, it would return the LogonPartial view, otherwise it would return the Authenticated view. Obviously, one of those is a login form/register link and the other is a Logout link. FWIW I strongly recommend you consider an upgrade to 2010 if possible - There are some huge improvements.